# Jquery .submit with function() does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am using Jquery and I want to automatically update my form on the page if I click on a link or perform some action. If I use .submit() it works fine, if I use .submit(function(e){}) the form will not submit. I need to get the response from the form submission, thats why i need the .submit(function(e){}) to work over the .submit(). Thanks.

I have a form:

```
  <form action="action.html" id="form1">
  </form>
```

I have a link:

```
 <a href="" data-id="1" class="myLink">Link</a>
```

When I click on the link I do the following:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.myLink', function(e) {
      // this will call a function to submit my form...
      var response = saveEmailDraft($(this).data('id'));
      e.preventDefault();
 });  

 function saveEmailDraft(id){
      $('#form' + id).submit(); // this works fine...
      $('#form' + id).submit(function(e){
          // this DOES NOT work...
          alert('my form submitted!');
      }); 

      // I've also tried;
      $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#form' + id).submit(); // this works fine...
           $('#form' + id).submit(function(e){
               // this DOES NOT work...
               alert('my form submitted!');
           });
      });

 }
```

Comment: You need to `.preventDefault()` on your form submission too.

Comment: How specifically does it "not work"?  Do you try to submit the form after setting that handler?  What happens when you do?  What are you expecting `var response` to even contain?  Why?  And doesn't the whole page reload when you first call `.submit()` anyway?

Comment: Nothing happen, there is no ajax request performed. When I just use .submit() the ajax request happens, .submit(function()) it bombs out.

Comment: So you call submit than you bind a method to it..... So you wonder why the something is not responding to the call that was already made....

Comment: @LargeTuna: There is no AJAX in this code.  And "it bombs out" doesn't really describe the problem.

Comment: Have you wrapped it in the right jquery ready() ? And you have included jquery before your js? If its 'bombing out', then you need to provide the errors found in your console.

Comment: Yes, I've tried adding document ready as well. My form is placed on the page with an ajax call, would this make a difference?

Comment: You can not get the response of a form submission! The page refreshes. What you want to do is not possible. You need to make the form submission with Ajax.

Comment: @LargeTuna: *"would this make a difference?"* - Maybe?  That depends on what that code you're not showing us is actually doing.  It may not be relevant at all.  What *is* relevant is defining specifically what about this is failing.  When you call `$('#form' + id).submit()` that's going to submit the form.  Unless something is preventing the default action, that's going to *refresh the page* and stop all other JavaScript from running.  We can sympathize that this "doesn't work" but you're going to have to be more descriptive than that.

Comment: Why don't you start by using relevant element as a `button` and with `form` attribute to submit the `form`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the event handler *before* you submit the form.

```
function saveEmailDraft(id){
    $('#form' + id).submit(function(e){
        alert('my form submitted!');
    }); 
    $('#form' + id).submit();
}
```

But this won't let you get the response from the form submission. The event handler is executed *before* the form data is sent to the server. When the form is submitted, the page reloads and all current scripts stop running.

If you want to get the response, you need to use `$.ajax` (or a shortcut like `$.get` or `$.post`) instead of `.submit()`.

Comment: Isn't this just calling the same thing twice?

Comment: No. `submit()` with an argument binds a handler, with no argument it submits the form.

Comment: @LargeTuna Read the documentation of things you do not understand. https://api.jquery.com/submit/